# user form is not displayed with some extra lines of code

Tags: excel, vba

Why does the userform (a barcode) not show up with this code (only timer is running):

```
Sub Barcode_Show()
    'show barcode form

    On Error GoTo Errorhandler
    
    Application.OnTime Now, "Barcode_Close"
    
   DoEvents
   Load form_Barcode
   With form_Barcode
       .Barcode128 = rngTarget.Value
       
       
       **If ActiveSheet.CodeName = wsPastorer Then
            .BarcodeLabel = "P" & TankCell.Value & " - " & ProduktCell.Value
       Else
            .BarcodeLabel = "T" & TankCell.Value & " - " & ProduktCell.Value
       End If**
       
       .Show
   End With
   
Exit Sub
Errorhandler:
    Call Barcode_Close
End Sub
```

When I change it to

```
DoEvents
   Load form_Barcode
   With form_Barcode
       .Barcode128 = rngTarget.Value
       .BarcodeLabel = "T" & TankCell.Value & " - " & ProduktCell.Value
       .Show
   End With
```

it will work.
I tried to have some other code in that place before, and it didn't work either. Why is it not possible and how to write the code so the form will show?

Comment: Comment the error handler and check if the code raises a runtime error - likely it never hits the `show`-command

Comment: @FunThomas THANK YOU Error was here: If ActiveSheet.CodeName = "wsPastorer" Then, I didn't wrote the ""

Comment: That error could have been prevented by using `Option Explicit` - no excuse to not use it!

Comment: @FunThomas Option Explicit was in the module, my fault was not to comment out the Errorhandler, as you suggested.